# Combining files

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I am new to scala. I have two RDD's and I need to separate out my training and testing data. In one file I have all the data and in another just the testing data. I need to remove the testing data from my complete data set.

The complete data file is of the format(userID,MovID,Rating,Timestamp):

```
res8: Array[String] = Array(1, 31, 2.5, 1260759144)
```

The test data file is of the format(userID,MovID):

```
res10: Array[String] = Array(1, 1172)
```

How do I generate ratings_train that will not have the caes matched with the testing dataset
I am using the following function but the returned list is showing empty:

```
  def create_training(data: RDD[String], ratings_test: RDD[String]): ListBuffer[Array[String]] = {
val ratings_split = dropheader(data).map(line => line.split(","))
val ratings_testing = dropheader(ratings_test).map(line => line.split(",")).collect()
var ratings_train = new ListBuffer[Array[String]]()
ratings_split.foreach(x => {
  ratings_testing.foreach(y => {
    if (x(0) != y(0) || x(1) != y(1)) {
      ratings_train += x
    }
  })
})
return ratings_train
```

}

EDIT: changed code but running into memory issues.

Comment: ratings_train is of type VAL that means it can't be change once assign the value `x :: ratings_train` will each time return the new object of list it will not append the data in `ratings_train`. try using VAL and use this
`ratings_train = x :: ratings_train`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work.

```
def create_training(data: RDD[String], ratings_test: RDD[String]): Array[Array[String]] = {
  val ratings_split = dropheader(data).map(line => line.split(","))
  val ratings_testing = dropheader(ratings_test).map(line => line.split(","))

  ratings_split.filter(x => {
    ratings_testing.exists(y =>
      (x(0) == y(0) && x(1) == y(1))
    ) == false
  })
}
```

1. The code snippets you posted are not logically correct. A row will only be part of the final data if it has no presence in the test data. But in the code you picked the row if it does not match **with any of the test data**. But we should check whether it does not match with **all of the test data** and then only we can decide whether it is a valid row or not.
2. You are using RDD, but now exploring the full power of them. I guess you are reading the input from a csv file. Then you can structure your data in the RDD, no need to spit the string based on comma character and manually processing them as ROW. You can take a look at the DataFrame API of spark. These links may help: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/spark_sql/spark_sql_dataframes.htm , http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#datasets-and-dataframes

**Using Regex:**

```
  def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
    // creating test data set
    val data = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      //      "userID, MovID, Rating, Timestamp",
      "1, 31, 2.5, 1260759144",
      "2, 31, 2.5, 1260759144"))

    val ratings_test = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(
      //      "userID, MovID",
      "1, 31",
      "2, 30",
      "30, 2"
    ))

    val result = getData(data, ratings_test).collect()
    // the result will only contain "2, 31, 2.5, 1260759144"
  }

  def getData(data: RDD[String], ratings_test: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = {
    val ratings = dropheader(data)
    val ratings_testing = dropheader(ratings_test)

    // Broadcasting the test rating data to all spark nodes, since we are collecting this before hand.
    // The reason we are collecting the test data is to avoid call collect in the filter logic
    val ratings_testing_bc = spark.sparkContext.broadcast(ratings_testing.collect.toSet)

    ratings.filter(rating => {
      ratings_testing_bc.value.exists(testRating => regexMatch(rating, testRating)) == false
    })
  }

  def regexMatch(data: String, testData: String): Boolean = {
    // Regular expression to find first two columns
    val regex = """^([^,]*), ([^,\r\n]*),?""".r

    val (dataCol1, dataCol2) = regex findFirstIn data match {
      case Some(regex(col1, col2)) => (col1, col2)
    }

    val (testDataCol1, testDataCol2) = regex findFirstIn testData match {
      case Some(regex(col1, col2)) => (col1, col2)
    }

    (dataCol1 == testDataCol1) && (dataCol2 == testDataCol2)
  }
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `==true` since we want to filter those x's which exisit in `ratings_testing` i.e the y's ?

Comment: Hi got it, filter is keeping the x values as opposed to filtering out. Am I right?

Comment: Umm, no.Because I have changed the condition too. Now for each y, we are checking if it is same as the x. Thats what being done by the exists() method. So if we get a match, we can safely say that, that x is present in test data and no need to check all the test data.
`(x(0) == y(0) && x(1) == y(1))`

Comment: Hi Can you explain how I can do a reqx match instead of splitting the string and then comparing x(0)y(0) and x(1)y(1). Since the data is huge this operation is causing a bottleneck and I think regex matching and storing RDD as string will be more efficient. I am using x.indexOf(y)==0 to match but it's not working

Comment: By **not working**, I think you meant it is giving compile error, right? If that is the case, it is because there is no exists method in RDD. I have updated the code in my answer by removing the split and keeping the result in RDD. Please see the  comment to understand what I am doing.